# Generation of report in Excel

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I have a spreadsheet that has 28 columns. I want to hide some of the column dynamically based on some condition like if there is no data it should be hided.  Is there a way so that the spreadsheet will automatically hide.
I have tried with this.

```
xlsTransformer.setColumnsToHide(new short[]{ (short)1, (short)3 } );
```

by referring [this](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/columnhiding.html) site.
but I got stuck. Please give me your suggestion.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: same thing xlsTransformer.setColumnsToHide(new short[]{ (short)1, (short)3 } ); printing i am not getting any error

Comment: You mean to say you're getting ` xlsTransformer.setColumnsToHide(new short[]{ (short)1, (short)3 } );`  as a text inside the cell?

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet for better understanding ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the statement. Following is the code snippet that I have tried. It hides the Columns B, C & D as we are specifying the numbers 1, 2 & 3.

```
XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
transformer.setColumnsToHide(new short[]{1, 2, 3});

Workbook workBook = transformer.transformXLS(inputStream, map);
```

I have tried with jXLS 1.0.6 version and following are the maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```